# "Система абсолютно не жизнеспособна" - ошибка? Слитно или раздельно нужно писать?

Tags: слитно-раздельно, прилагательные

> Элла Памфилова: «Система, созданная Путиным, Медведевым, Ельциным, абсолютно не жизнеспособна» (заголовок, "[Слон](https://slon.ru/posts/65853)")

Мне кажется, что должно быть "нежизнеспособна", без пробела. Но "Слон" - качественное СМИ..

Может, раздельно - правильно?

P.S. Посмотрел поподробнее - это у них цитата с "Радио Свобода", так что "Слон" винить нельзя, наверное, если это ошибка.

Comment: "Но "Слон" - качественное СМИ.." М-да. Отчетливо нерусское средство МИ.

Comment: @Варяг-91 - если СМИ пишет на русском языке и не изобретает альтернативную реальность в три короба подобно подконтрольным Кремлю СМИ, для меня это "качественное *русское* СМИ". Это и Русская Служба BBC, и Слон, и Медуза, и "Новая Газета", и, скажем, "[Гордон](http://gordonua.com/)".

Comment: Нашли место для выражения своих политических убеждений. Эти-то, перечисленные Вами, кому подконтрольны? И почему от заграничности источника финансирования они станут качественными русскими? Лучше читайте словари и справочники. Пробандеровский Гордон и говорит-то на суржике и с бердичевским прононсом, уши вянут.

Comment: Варяг-91, даже самые авторитетные издания допускают ошибки.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Полные и краткие прилагательные, имеющие при себе пояснительные наречия меры и степени (крайне, весьма, абсолютно и т. д.) с частицей *не* пишутся слитно (абсолютно нетерпимое отношение).

Розенталь. Справочник по русскому языку. XVII, §67, п. 6, прим. 2.

Comment: _V.V.:  Полные и краткие прилагательные, имеющие при себе пояснительные наречия меры и степени (крайне, весьма, **абсолютно** и т. д.)… Розенталь. Справочник по русскому языку. XVII, § 67, п. 6, прим. 2._ === V.V., по-моему, Вы неточно воспроизвели цитату из Розенталя. Разве Розенталь что-либо говорил о слове **абсолютно** в параграфе, на который Вы ссылаетесь?

Answer (score 8):

В примере, который Вы приводите, корректно слитное написание, о чем свидетельствует наречие "абсолютно" и сам контекст. В тексте не отрицается жизнеспособность, а утверждается нежизнеспособность..

> Такие слова, как **абсолютно, совершенно,** могут употребляться и в сочетаниях этого типа (подчеркивая утверждение), и при словах, пишущихся с **не** раздельно (усиливая отрицание, см. § 147, п. 2). Ср., напр.: абсолютно (совершенно) неудачное выступление и он человек абсолютно (совершенно) не старый (возможно синонимичное сочетание вовсе не старый.

См.: Академический справочник Лопатина.

Comment: _Серж: В тексте не отрицается жизнеспособность, а утверждается_. === Утверждается **жизнеспособность?** Если утверждается, то, скорее,  **НЕжизнеспособность**.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание!

Answer (score 4):

> *«Система, созданная Путиным, Медведевым, Ельциным, абсолютно не жизнеспособна».*
>
> Мне кажется, что должно быть "нежизнеспособна", без пробела.

.

**Правильны оба написания  — *и слитное, и раздельное.***

Сошлюсь на тот же параграф в [***"Полном академическом справочнике" под ред. Лопатина***](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=79#pp79), на который ранее уже ссылался ***Серж*** в этой теме:

> **§ 148.** С существительными, прилагательными, наречиями на ***-о*** отрицание ***не*** пишется слитно в следующих случаях.
>
> <…>
>
> **4.** Если при прилагательном, а также при наречии на ***-о*** имеются слова *очень, крайне, весьма, чрезвычайно, явно, довольно
>   (довольно-таки), достаточно, вопиюще, исключительно, в высшей степени*
>   — слова со значением степени проявления признака, подчеркивающие
>   утверждение...
>
> **Примечание.** Однако такие слова, как ***абсолютно, совершенно***, могут употребляться и в сочетаниях этого типа (подчеркивая
>   утверждение), и при словах, пишущихся с ***не*** раздельно (усиливая
>   отрицание)…

.

[**Из  ответа справочной службы русского языка Грамоты.ру:**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=287811)

> ***Эта система абсолютно не/жизнеспособна.***
>
> Написание зависит от смысла. Слитное написание подчеркивает
>   утверждение (утверждается нежизнеспособность), раздельное написание
>   подчеркивает отрицание. **Решение о слитном или раздельном написании
>   принимает автор текста.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Интересно, спасибо, Слава!